# Transforming multidimensional array data returned from database

Tags: codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I am having problems with working with multidimensional array data.
I have 2 tables (maincategories and categories) which I joined.

Table Maincategories:
**id, maincategory**

Table Categories:
**id, maincategory_id, category**

```
    $this->db->select('m.id, m.name_en AS maincategory')
            ->select('c.name_en AS category')
            ->from('categories AS c')
            ->join('maincategories AS m', 'c.maincategory_id=m.id', 'left');
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

This results in all 4 categories being listed as below.

```
[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 7
        [maincategory] => Career
        [category] => Business Sales
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [maincategory] => Accommodation
        [category] => Camping
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 6
        [maincategory] => Accommodation
        [category] => Hostels
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 7
        [maincategory] => Career
        [category] => Career Events
    )
```

4 unique categories are in the list while **2** of them belong to **maincategory: Accommodaton** and the other **2** categories belong to **maincategory: Career**. What I wanted to **achieve** is that **each maincategory is only listed ONCE and the categories shall fall under that main_category**. Something like this:

```
[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 7
        [maincategory] => Career
        [category] => array(Career Events, Business Sales, .....)
    )
[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 7
        [maincategory] => Accommodation
        [category] => array(Hostels, Camping, .....)
    )
```

The array dump will maybe/probably look different in its end result but I hope you understand what I am trying to achieve. I read quite a bit about transforming multidimensional arrays. I just can't get my head around it yet. Thanks a lot for any direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
function fetch_all(){
    $data  = array();
    $first = $this->db->select('id, maincategory')->get('maincategory')->result_array();
    if( is_array( $first ) && count( $first ) > 0 ){
        foreach( $first as $key => $each ){
           $data[$key]['category_id']   = $each['id']; #main category id
           $data[$key]['maincategory']  = $each['id']; #main category name
           $second  = $this->db->select('category')->where_in('maincategory_id', $each['id'])->get('categories')->result_array();
           $data[$key]['category']      = $second;     #all sub-category(s) array
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using so many db calls, try using the underscore.php library http://brianhaveri.github.io/Underscore.php/

I've outlined a few examples of how to use it for this case here:  http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2012/08/no-more-machine-gunning-use-underscore-php

Edit